# Confused by the definition about the inertial frame of reference

Tags: inertial-frames, equilibrium

In Wikipedia, you can find the definition of the [inertial frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference), which states:

> In classical physics and special relativity, an inertial frame of reference (also inertial reference frame or inertial frame, Galilean reference frame or inertial space) is a frame of reference that describes time and space homogeneously, isotropically, and in a time-independent manner.

Actually, I don't think it's a good definition or a good description. So just like we define the equilibrium state in thermodynamics, can we propose a similar definition by comparison? I mean can we take three reference systems with different constant velocities and make a comparison between the corresponding state of motion and then give the definition of the inertial frame of reference?

Comment: You need to explain, to me at least, why you don't like the definition and what you mean by your reference to equilibrium. Sorry, I just don't follow you :)

Comment: You need at least to add to your quote the last sentence of the first paragraph which is very important: *The physics of a system in an inertial frame have no causes external to the system.*

Comment: Add some description, is that correct?